# dynamic div over the first image

Tags: jquery

i am using the code bellow to create a dynamic div with jquery and display it under the first image. Everything works great.

But how can place this dynamic div over my image and not under?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                       
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after("<div style='width:800px; height:90px; float: left; margin-top:10px;'><a href='http://www.demo.com'>MyLink</a></div>");
});
</script>
```

Inside Body:

```
<div class="gdl-blog-full" style="width:650px; height:390px;">
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="4134ed_L" width="650" height="390" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-8500">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the below css

```
top:0; //moves to top of the image which you need
position: absolute;
```

using **`absolute`** position, you can position the element but make sure of responsive.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wuEc/)

Comment: It works only if the image is at the top left corner of the page. You'll need a `position:relative;` somewhere..

Comment: @Oliboy50 yes, right.  But you can change the position of `top` or you can use the other properties wisely as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `position;realtive` to parent & `position:absolute` to childs. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position 
Use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to place elements over or under.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` will need a `z-index` property and will need to be positioned `absolute`.

Like so:

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first").after("<div style='position: absolute; z-index: 9999; width:800px; height:90px; float: left; margin-top:10px;'><a href='http://www.demo.com'>MyLink</a></div>");
```

You can then position your `div` accordingly using the CSS properties `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`.